# In Queuing Theory, what is the relationship between processing time and average queuing delay?

Tags: queue

Consider a system where jobs are queued and processed in FIFO order.  They currently wait an average of N seconds before being processed. If jobs take an average of M seconds to process, what will be the impact to N if we reduce the processing time to M/2 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to read these two links on queuing theory. The latter contains a number of useful formulas for calculating the average lengths of queues and wait times and a good explanation of the factors involved.

[Queuing Theory for Dummies](http://www.embedded.com/story/OEG20010312S0101) (no offence!)

[How to size message queues](http://www.embedded.com/9901103?_requestid=647333)